# <url> malformed 500 Internal Server Error - ClientException BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle

Tags: security, authentication, symfony, cas

I'm trying to use BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle in a project but I have an issue.

## config.yml

```
be_simple_sso_auth:
    admin_sso:
        protocol:
            id: cas
            version: 2
        server:
            id: cas
            login_url: https://cas.XXX.com/ID/login
            logout_url: https://cas.XXX.com/ID/logout
            #validation_url: https://cas.XXX.com/ID/serviceValidate
```

## security.yml

```
security:

    providers:
        # Proveedor administradores
        administradores:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin: { password: 123456, roles: ROLE_ADMIN}


    firewalls:
        # Backend
        backend:
            pattern: ^/backend/.*$
            trusted_sso:
                manager: admin_sso
                login_action: false #BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle:TrustedSso:login
                logout_action: false #BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle:TrustedSso:logout
                create_users: true
                created_users_roles: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]
                check_path: /backend/login_check
                login_path: /backend/login
                use_referer: true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/backend, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I create this memory providers because if not i get this error message:

```
InvalidConfigurationException: The child node "providers" at path "security" must be configured.
```

Then when i access to /backend it redirect to login URL: https://cas.XXX.com/ID/login, up here all right! but when I start session it redirect to:

```
/backend/login_check?ticket=ST-1383036359rD96A55DD1B77B754D4
```

and i have a Exception

```
<url> malformed
500 Internal Server Error - ClientException
```

I know thats is because of the "?ticket=ST-1383036359rD96A55DD1B77B754D4" but i dont know how to solve.

thanks!

----- 29/10/13 12:27 UPDATED -----

## parameters.yml

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    be_simple.sso_auth.client.option.curlopt_ssl_verifypeer.value: false
```

## routing.yml

```
backend_login:
    path: /login

backend_login_check:
    path: /login_check

backend_logout:
    path: /logout
```

Comment: It could be due to curl failure with self-signed certificates. Try adding `be_simple.sso_auth.client.option.curlopt_ssl_verifypeer.value: false` to your parameters.yml (In production you should have valid certificates and this option turned on)

Comment: thanks! but the problem continues  :(

Comment: Perhaps the users provider is misconfigured. How I should indicate that the provider is the CAS? Would I have to have the list of usernames in my local database as provider?

Comment: Did you come up to a solution to this problem ??